# Rcpp+Eclipse on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, r, osx-mountain-lion, rcpp

I am trying to get started using Rccp and decided to use Eclipse as a development environment since I already use StatEt for R. I am having trouble getting even a simple program to compile and run though, and would appreciate some help!

Briefly I tried to follow the instructions on the blog: http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170 exactly for setting up Rcpp, RInside and Eclipse, and for the example program. I am running on Mountain Lion, and installed g++ using the command line options in XCode. I think I've faithfully followed all the steps in the blog, but cannot get the program to compile. I think the problem is in the way the header files are included, as indicated from the snippet of the output below. As far as I can tell, line 52 of `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstring` is an include statement for `<string.h>` and the compiler includes `Rccp/include/string.h` instead of the `string.h` from `std` that is found earlier on the include path.

I am a novice in C++ so I'd really appreciate some pointers on how to proceed.

-Krishna

```
16:22:38 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project MyTestRCppPackage ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -DINSIDE -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/RInside/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -arch x86_64 -v -o src/main.o ../src/main.cpp 
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
 /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/cc1plus -quiet -v -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/RInside/include -imultilib x86_64 -iprefix /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ -dD -D__DYNAMIC__ -DINSIDE ../src/main.cpp -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mmacosx-version-min=10.8.3 -m64 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip src/main.o -g3 -O0 -Wall -version -fmessage-length=0 -D__private_extern__=extern -o /var/folders/hc/vqp48jt56_v332kc3dqyf5780000gn/T//ccqdmOKI.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/../../../../i686-apple-darwin11/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11/x86_64"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/../../../../i686-apple-darwin11/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/include
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp
 /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/RInside/include
 /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
GNU C++ version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00) (i686-apple-darwin11)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00).
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=150 --param ggc-min-heapsize=65536
Compiler executable checksum: b37fef824b01c0a99fb2679acf3b04f1
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstring:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/memory:53,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/hashtable:56,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/unordered_map:37,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:158,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:26,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from ../src/main.cpp:8:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:52: error: 'internal' has not been declared
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:52: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:52: error: expected ';' before '<' token
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:65: error: expected `)' before 'charsxp'
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:70: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:75: error: expected unqualified-id before '&' token
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:75: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:75: error: 'Rcpp::String::String()' cannot be overloaded
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:55: error: with 'Rcpp::String::String()'
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:85: error: 'Rcpp::String::String(int)' cannot be overloaded
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:70: error: with 'Rcpp::String::String(int)'
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:88: error: expected `)' before 'x'
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:89: error: expected `)' before 'x'
```

Comment: I didn't see a step where you got instructed to install XCode. Exactly how much of a novice are you?

Comment: I needed a c++ compiler so I decided to use g++ from XCode through installing the command line tools. I haven't programmed in C++ for awhile and never on a Mac.

Comment: It appears that this is less an Rcpp question and more an RInside one. Can you get the package to build using Rcpp as outlined in the instructions in the blog post? Secondly, there seems to be a problem with eclipse finding your c++ paths. Can you create and run a regular c++ project (no R) using Eclipse? If so, did you start the steps in the blog post by creating a c++ project?

Comment: Hello Ian: I cannot get the package to build, I've posted snippet of the errors above. There is indeed a conflict between include files with the same name (string.h and Rcpp/string.h) and, unfortunately, the wrong one appears to have been chosen, possibly because include paths specified with the -I option are searched before the default ones. I am able to run simple C++ programs without Rcpp, after creating them within Eclipse. I also faithfully followed the steps to create the c++ project, including all the changes to the tool chain settings etc. - Krishna

Comment: I think this question is the about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975638/windows-r-inside-rcpp-eclipse?rq=1

Comment: There are two modes of building. The output pasted above is building via RInside (step 7). I was asking if R CMD build works from within Eclipse (step 5). It appears that the default headers are not loaded second, rather not at all. The compiler is telling you that it can't find them "Ignoring nonexistent directory." Manually check the existence of those directories and change the pointers in the project properties if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, the issue I faced was that include files in `Rcpp` with the sames names as those in `std` were in conflict. In particular, `string.h` from `Rcpp` was being included at a point where `string.h` from `std` was the right choice, and, as far as I could tell, this was due to the fact that paths specified via the `-I` directive are searched prior to the default paths.

I tried many different alternatives to solve this, including removing and re-installing XCode and the associated Command Line tools, as well as installing another g++ compiler using macports. None of these resolved the issue. I then used the `-idirafter` directive instead of the `-I` directive for the search path for include files for Rcpp and R. I got this hint from [gcc include order broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893800/gcc-include-order-broken). This worked since these directories are now searched after the default paths. This precludes (at least so far!) the possibility that `string.h` from `std` and `string.h` from `Rcpp` come into conflict.

To get step 5 of http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170 to work I had to set the `-idirafter` paths in  `PKG_CPPFLAGS` in the file `Makevars`.

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There are two entirely separate issues here:

1. Get all you need for Rcpp installed.  OS X aspects should be documented on the relevant page maintained by Simon.  If you have the tools, and have Rcpp install, then you should be able to do `cppFunction('double nPi(int x) { return x*M_PI; }')` which is uses functions supplied with Rcpp to create a callable C++ functions accessible to you as `nPi()` -- and `nPi(2)` should return a value.
2. Your choice of IDE and its settings.  This is has little to do with 1. apart from requiring it to work to.

So I would work on 1. and see if I got that sorted out first, and only then turn to 2.

Comment: Hello Dirk:
Thank you for the quick response, and thanks for the great package! Indeed, I have 1 covered, since I've installed Rcpp and tried out a few examples from your vignettes, and also the example above. I wanted to get a working Eclipse environment to do development with Rcpp, hence the question.

Comment: ok, so I tried many different alternatives to solve this, including removing and re-installing XCode and the associated Command Line tools, as well as installing another g++ compiler using macports. None of these resolved the issue. I then used the -idirafter directive instead of the -I directive to include the search path for include files for Rcpp and R. This worked since these directories are searched after the default paths. This precludes (at least so far!) the possibility that `string.h` from `std` and `string.h` from `Rcpp` come into conflict. Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to remove include

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp
```

because it is:

- unnecessary, as all R imports are in form `<Rcpp/XXX>`
- causes this issue, as compiler looks for `string.h` in `Rcpp` directory (when it shouldn't).